# Finishing one activitiy, moving to next activity and then return to previous activity

Tags: android, activity-finish, start-activity

so I am new to android development and I am stuck with small problem.
I got this code: `

```
Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent(Menu.this, pistols.class));
        finish();
    }

});`
```

That part is working fine, but when I start next Activity, and I want to return to previous activity using hardware device button(back button) it closes application instead of returing me to previous activity.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one helps

```
Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent(Menu.this, pistols.class));

}});
```

another way around. 
you can override onBackPressed. start the first activity from there.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
// call the first activity here
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :) .. keep coding

Answer (score 3):

Remove `finish()`. It should fix it, because you call `finish() it kills the activity and removes it from the back stack thus you can't return to it by pressing the back button.

Comment: it may help user when you post answers with proper comenting

Comment: Yeah but what about memory usage? I tried without that and I get this
http://i.stack.imgur.com/h9ZA0.png

Comment: @user3231871 are you using image any where?

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent(Menu.this, pistols.class));

    }

});`
```

Remove `finish`

Answer (score 0):

please search or do RnD about the activityforresult

Answer (score 0):

in your code **startactivity(...)** will start the new activity and the very next line i.e **finish()** will finishes the current activity. so you cannot return to previous activity after you have pressed back button.